# Direct Sound: How do I read captured data from a small buffer?

Tags: c++, audio, wav, directsound

I'm trying to capture waveforms of floating point PCM data from a microphone. The application is only asking for a small number of samples each cycle (For 20'000Hz and a frame size of 0.003s, it would ask for 60 samples)

I would like to set the buffer size depending on how many ms the app is interested in but it seems that `dwBufferBytes` has to be a certain size. Instead, I set it to nAvgBytesPerSec and only lock/copy 60 samples each time (even though much more data would be available to read)

Is this a valid approach or is there a different way to throttle the sound driver? Is there a way to reduce the size of the buffer to only give me as much data as the app is requesting? I don't want to get a ton of sound
    data if the application only wants 60 values.

Using this approach, I certainly will run into problems if the buffer catches up with my (slow) read cursor.

```
    unsigned short channelNum = 2;
    unsigned short bitsPerSample = 32;
    unsigned long sampleRate = 20000;
    unsigned short blockAlign = (channelNum * bitsPerSample) / 8;
    unsigned long avgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * blockAlign;

    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT, channelNum, sampleRate, avgBytesPerSec, blockAlign, bitsPerSample, 0 };

    unsigned int mSampleBufferSize = 60; // 1400

    DSCBUFFERDESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSCBUFFERDESC);
    bufferDesc.dwFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.dwBufferBytes = wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec;
    bufferDesc.dwReserved = 0;
    bufferDesc.lpwfxFormat = &wfx;
    bufferDesc.dwFXCount = 0;
    bufferDesc.lpDSCFXDesc = NULL;

    IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer *buffer = 0;
    bool bufferRunning = false;
    if (directSound && capture)
    {
        hr = capture->CreateCaptureBuffer(&bufferDesc, &buffer, NULL);
        if (FAILED(hr))
           std::cout << "SampleThread() -- Error creating DirectSoundCaptureBuffer " << endl;
        else
        {
            hr = buffer->Start(DSCBSTART_LOOPING);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                bufferRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void* primaryBuffer = NULL;
    unsigned long primaryBufferSizeBytes = 0;
    void* secondaryBuffer = NULL;
    unsigned long secondaryBufferSize = 0;
    bool mStopExecution = false;
    unsigned long lastReadPosition = 0;


    if (directSound && capture && buffer)
    {
        while (!mStopExecution)
        {
            DWORD readPos;
            WORD remainingSize = 0;
            DWORD capturePos;
            hr = buffer->GetCurrentPosition(&capturePos, &readPos);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                cout << "SampleThread() -- Error GetCurrentPosition" << endl;
                return 0;
            }


            buffer->Lock(lastReadPos, mSampleBufferSize, &primaryBuffer, &primaryBufferSizeBytes, &secondaryBuffer, &secondaryBufferSize, NULL);
            memcpy(mBuffer, (float*)primaryBuffer, primaryBufferSizeBytes / sizeof(float));

             // .... copy secondary buffer
             hr = buffer->Unlock(primaryBuffer, primaryBufferSizeBytes, secondaryBuffer, secondaryBufferSize);
            lastReadPosition = (lastReadPosition + mSampleBufferSize) % bufferDesc.dwBufferBytes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: DirectSound is an ancient API these days. Unless you need to run on Windows XP, you should look at using WASAPI instead.

Comment: I was looking into that. But the problem is, that it's not possible to set a custom sample rate

Comment: The audio device driver is using a fixed sample rate, and the samples are being source-rate converted in software by the DirectSound capture. WASAPI is just leaving SRC to your application.

Comment: Using WASAPI would leave me with the same problem though: `IAudioCaptureClient` returns too much data when calling `GetBuffer()`. I don't see what the advantage of switching would be (considering I would have to do SRC myself)